# Credit report in Italy

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, credit-history, italy

I am Italian, looking to move back to Italy.
I'd like to know if Italy has some sort of credit-score or credit history and this is actually checked on mortgage application?

Is credit score report really checked when buying something on credit, like a mortgage, furniture repaid monthly or opening a new credit card?

How evolved is the credit-history system?

Comment: It seems Experian is present. Can't read Italian. http://www.experian.it/consumer-information/informazioni-sui-privati.html

Answer (score 1):

Banca d'Italia manages the [Centrale Rischi](https://www.bancaditalia.it/servizi-cittadino/servizi/accesso-cr/), that can be accessed not only by companies but individuals as well. It stores information about credit that has been assigned and errors in payments. It is checked for mortgages.